# I'd just like to know as many expressions as possible - movie + show/ play

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's an original sentence. But I'd just like to know as many expressions as possible so that I can use and understand whichever.

## We won't be showing any movies on Christmas day.

> 1. Not any movies won't be playing  on Christmas day.
> 2. Not any movies won't be being shown on Christmas day.
> 3. There are no movies playing on Christmas day.
> 4. There will be no movies playing on Christmas day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Not any movies won't be playing on Christmas day.

You're using a double negation here, so you're basically saying that there is not a single movie that will not be shown on Christmas day, which is the same as saying that **all** movies **will be playing** on Christmas day. Rephrase your sentence like so:

> 1. Not any movies will be playing on Christmas day.

This sentence would probably be more idiomatic if you changed *not any* to *no*:

> 1. No movies will be playing on Christmas day.

---

In the second sentence, you also have a double negation:

> 2. Not any movies won't be being shown on Christmas day.

*...won't be being shown* is syntactically correct but sounds off and, to be honest, I have never heard it being used by anyone. You can leave out one auxiliary and retain the meaning. The *being* is obsolete here, because it focuses on duration. However, since no movie will be shown at all, there is no need to focus on the duration of the *showing*:

> 2. No movies **will be shown** on Christmas day.

---

> 3. There are no movies playing on Christmas day.
> 4. There will be no movies playing on Christmas day.

These sentences are both correct. Sentence 3 uses a simple present (*are*) to express a future, which is perfectly acceptable when talking about things that are *fixed*, such as time-tables, schedules or in this case the programmation.
Sentence 4 uses a simple future and is also a correct sentence.